# Unable to verify smart contract on polygoanMumbai using VSCode

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, etherscan

I tried to verify my contract with constructor arguments but hardhat throwing that error everytime my smart contract file is given below
**Domain.sol**

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

// We first import some OpenZeppelin Contracts.
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

import {StringUtils} from "./libraries/StringUtils.sol";
// We import another help function
import {Base64} from "./libraries/Base64.sol";

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Domains is ERC721URIStorage {
    // Here's our domain TLD!

    // Magic given to us by OpenZeppelin to help us keep track of tokenIds.
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    string public tld;

    // We'll be storing our NFT images on chain as SVGs
    string svgPartOne = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="270" height="270" fill="none"><path fill="url(#B)" d="M0 0h270v270H0z"/><defs><filter id="A" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="270" width="270"><feDropShadow dx="0" dy="1" stdDeviation="2" flood-opacity=".225" width="200%" height="200%"/></filter></defs><path d="M 64.285156 52.769531 L 105.675781 122.433594 C 106.085938 123.125 106.828125 123.550781 107.632812 123.550781 C 108.433594 123.550781 109.175781 123.125 109.589844 122.433594 L 128.328125 90.894531 L 147.0625 122.433594 C 147.476562 123.125 148.21875 123.550781 149.023438 123.550781 C 149.824219 123.550781 150.566406 123.125 150.980469 122.433594 L 192.367188 52.769531 C 192.789062 52.058594 192.800781 51.179688 192.394531 50.457031 C 191.988281 49.742188 191.230469 49.296875 190.410156 49.296875 L 169.480469 49.296875 C 168.671875 49.296875 167.921875 49.730469 167.511719 50.429688 L 151.105469 78.582031 C 150.464844 79.671875 150.832031 81.078125 151.917969 81.71875 C 153.003906 82.359375 154.398438 81.996094 155.035156 80.902344 L 170.785156 53.886719 L 186.390625 53.886719 L 149.023438 116.78125 L 130.984375 86.421875 L 150.980469 52.769531 C 151.402344 52.058594 151.410156 51.179688 151.003906 50.457031 C 150.601562 49.742188 149.84375 49.296875 149.023438 49.296875 L 128.089844 49.296875 C 127.28125 49.296875 126.53125 49.730469 126.125 50.429688 L 109.714844 78.582031 C 109.078125 79.671875 109.441406 81.078125 110.527344 81.71875 C 111.613281 82.359375 113.011719 81.996094 113.648438 80.902344 L 129.398438 53.886719 L 145 53.886719 L 126.375 85.234375 C 126.371094 85.242188 126.363281 85.253906 126.359375 85.265625 L 107.632812 116.78125 L 70.261719 53.886719 L 103.796875 53.886719 L 99.210938 62.371094 C 98.609375 63.480469 99.015625 64.875 100.125 65.480469 C 101.230469 66.085938 102.613281 65.675781 103.214844 64.5625 L 109.636719 52.6875 C 110.019531 51.976562 110.003906 51.113281 109.59375 50.417969 C 109.179688 49.722656 108.4375 49.296875 107.632812 49.296875 L 66.242188 49.296875 C 65.421875 49.296875 64.664062 49.742188 64.257812 50.457031 C 63.855469 51.179688 63.863281 52.058594 64.285156 52.769531" fill="#A274FF"/><defs><linearGradient id="B" x1="0" y1="0" x2="270" y2="270" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop stop-color="#120037"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#120037" stop-opacity=".99"/></linearGradient></defs><rect x="50" y="211" rx="20" ry="20" width="170" height="40" style="stroke:white; stroke-width:3 ;opacity:0.9"/><text x="50%" y="240" rx="20" ry="20" font-size="25" fill="#FFF" font-family="Plus Jakarta Sans,DejaVu Sans,Noto Color Emoji,Apple Color Emoji,sans-serif" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle">.Web3Shift</text><text x="50%" y="200" font-size="27" fill="#fff" filter="url(#A)" font-family="Plus Jakarta Sans,DejaVu Sans,Noto Color Emoji,Apple Color Emoji,sans-serif" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle">';
    string svgPartTwo = "</text></svg>";

    mapping(string => address) public domains;
    mapping(string => string) public records;

    address payable public owner;

    constructor(string memory _tld)
        payable
        ERC721("Web3Shift Name Service", "W3C")
    {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
        tld = _tld;
        console.log("%s name service deployed", _tld);
    }

    function register(string calldata name) public payable {
        require(domains[name] == address(0));

        uint256 _price = price(name);
        require(msg.value >= _price, "Not enough Matic paid");

        // Combine the name passed into the function  with the TLD
        string memory _name = string(abi.encodePacked(name, ".", tld));

        string memory just_name = string(abi.encodePacked(name));
        // Create the SVG (image) for the NFT with the name
        string memory finalSvg = string(
            abi.encodePacked(svgPartOne, just_name, svgPartTwo)
        );
        uint256 newRecordId = _tokenIds.current();
        uint256 length = StringUtils.strlen(name);
        string memory strLen = Strings.toString(length);

        console.log(
            "Registering %s.%s on the contract with tokenID %d",
            name,
            tld,
            newRecordId
        );

        // Create the JSON metadata of our NFT. We do this by combining strings and encoding as base64
        string memory json = Base64.encode(
            abi.encodePacked(
                '{"name": "',
                _name,
                '", "description": "A domain on the Web3Shift name service", "image": "data:image/svg+xml;base64,',
                Base64.encode(bytes(finalSvg)),
                '","length":"',
                strLen,
                '"}'
            )
        );

        string memory finalTokenUri = string(
            abi.encodePacked("data:application/json;base64,", json)
        );

        console.log(
            "\n--------------------------------------------------------"
        );
        console.log("Final tokenURI", finalTokenUri);
        console.log(
            "--------------------------------------------------------\n"
        );

        _safeMint(msg.sender, newRecordId);
        _setTokenURI(newRecordId, finalTokenUri);
        domains[name] = msg.sender;

        _tokenIds.increment();
    }

    // This function will give us the price of a domain based on length
    function price(string calldata name) public pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 len = StringUtils.strlen(name);
        require(len > 0);
        if (len == 1) {
            return 3 * 10**17; // 5 MATIC = 5 000 000 000 000 000 000 (18 decimals). We're going with 0.5 Matic cause the faucets don't give a lot
        } else if (len == 3) {
            return 2 * 10**17; // To charge smaller amounts, reduce the decimals. This is 0.3
        } else {
            return 1 * 10**17;
        }
    }

    // Other functions unchanged

    function getAddress(string calldata name) public view returns (address) {
        // Check that the owner is the transaction sender
        return domains[name];
    }

    function setRecord(string calldata name, string calldata record) public {
        // Check that the owner is the transaction sender
        require(domains[name] == msg.sender);
        records[name] = record;
    }

    function getRecord(string calldata name)
        public
        view
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return records[name];
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(isOwner());
        _;
    }

    function isOwner() public view returns (bool) {
        return msg.sender == owner;
    }

    function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
        uint256 amount = address(this).balance;

        (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: amount}("");
        require(success, "Failed to withdraw Matic");
    }
}
```

**hardhat.config.js**

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan");

const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

//require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
    solidity: "0.8.10",
    etherscan: {
        apiKey: {
            goerli: "UGFT5V9QWSATQN8ERITGYZPT3VHN8EGZD3",
            polygonMumbai: "TIG8FUTP9DKH2KN4957JCWIDWQSPQNEFKN",
        }
    },
    networks: {
        mumbai: {
            url: process.env.url,
            accounts: [process.env.key],
        },
        goerli: {
            url: `https://eth-goerli.alchemyapi.io/v2/${ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`,
            accounts: [process.env.goerli],
        }
    },
    polygon: {
        apiKey: {
            polygonMumbai: "TIG8FUTP9DKH2KN4957JCWIDWQSPQNEFKN",
        }
    },
};
```

**npx hardhat verify --network mumbai 0xB775e8D2A925836E216EcDea9E23A72c4AbF222f**

```
(node:25360) ExperimentalWarning: stream/web is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Nothing to compile
Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: The constructor for contracts/Domains.sol:Domains has 1 parameters
but 0 arguments were provided instead.
```

When I pass the argument then

**npx hardhat verify --network mumbai 0xB775e8D2A925836E216EcDea9E23A72c4AbF222f 1**

```
(node:26960) ExperimentalWarning: stream/web is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Nothing to compile
Successfully submitted source code for contract
contracts/Domains.sol:Domains at 0xB775e8D2A925836E216EcDea9E23A72c4AbF222f
for verification on the block explorer. Waiting for verification result...

We tried verifying your contract Domains without including any unrelated one, but it failed.
Trying again with the full solc input used to compile and deploy it.
This means that unrelated contracts may be displayed on Etherscan...

Successfully submitted source code for contract
contracts/Domains.sol:Domains at 0xB775e8D2A925836E216EcDea9E23A72c4AbF222f
for verification on the block explorer. Waiting for verification result...

Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: The contract verification failed.
Reason: Fail - Unable to verify
```